# implicit declaration of function

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, gcc-warning

GCC typically yields this warning when the proper header file is not included.  This link --> [www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_19.html](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_19.html) says that because the function declaration is implicit (rather than explicitly declared via a header) the wrong argument types could actually be passed to the function, yielding incorrect results.  I don't understand this.  Does this mean the compiler generates code that pushes something, of the machine's word size, onto the stack for the callee to consume, and hopes for the best?

Detail is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If the compiler doesn't have specific information about how the argument should be passed, such as when there's no prototype or for arguments that are passed where the prototype have an ellipsis ('...'), the compiler follows certain rules for passing the arguments. These rule basically follow what occurred in pre-standard (or K&R) C - before prototypes were used. Paraphrased from C99 6.5.2.2/6 "Function calls":

```
* the integer promotions are applied
* if the argument has float type it's promoted to double
```

After these default argument promotions are applied, the argument is simply copied to wherever the compiler normally copies arguments (generally, the stack). So a struct argument would be copied to the stack.

If the actual function implementation doesn't match how the compiler creates the parameters, then you get undefined behavior (with exceptions for signed/unsigned mismatch if the value can be represented or pointers to char and pointers to void can be mixed/matched).

Also in C90, if the function is implicitly declared (which C99 doesn't permit, though it does permit functions without prototypes), the return value is defaulted as `int`.  Once again, the the actual function returns something else, undefined behavior results.

Answer (score 3):

In classic K&R C, that's pretty much what happened; there were default coercions (anything smaller than `(int)` was promoted to `(int)`, for example), and for backwards compatibility any function without a prototype is still called that way, but by and large the only indication you got for passing the wrong type was a weird result or maybe a core dump.  Which is where you get in trouble, as when the function has a prototype the exact (not coerced/promoted) value is pushed.  So if you're passing a `(char)`, if there's a prototype in scope then a single byte is pushed by the caller, otherwise 4 bytes (on most current platforms).  If the caller and callee disagree about this, Bad Things happen.

Comment: Normal calling conventions still pass a `char` as 1 byte in a full-width arg-passing slot (in a register or on the stack).  Even with a prototype, 4 `char` arguments don't pack into the same space as a single 32-bit `int` on the stack.  You *could* design a calling convention that packs stack args like a struct would, but that happens to be not how any x86 calling conventions are designed, nor any for any other ISA I'm aware of.

Comment: So the real badness is if the caller passes a wider argument, and instead of implicitly converting (by truncation), it takes up 2 arg-passing slots.  Or if the callee is *expecting* a wider argument, like an `int64_t` that on a 32-bit machine takes 2 registers or 2 reg-sized locations on the stack, but the caller only passes a small integer that takes up 1 slot.  Or the caller passes a double but the callee was expecting an integer or vice versa: again no implicit conversion, and the types are stored with different representations and maybe in different registers.